# Can you put an electrical switch inside a walk-in closet according to NEC?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, nec

I have a walk-in closet where I would like to put a switched light ceiling-mounted fixture.

According to NEC can I put the switch *inside* the closet (next to the door), or does the switch need to be on the wall, outside the closet?

I would prefer a citation of the code (if there is one) so I can ensure I follow the rules.

Comment: Pull string fixtures or fixtures with motion sensors could save you a switch.

Comment: We already have a light socket with a pull string. It doesn’t illuminate the space enough and the wife can’t reach it too well. The idea is to have a motion sensor and smart switch to turn it on / off.

Comment: If you're in California, make sure you look into the California Energy Code. I'm a bit rusty on it, but there are additional requirements for closets/switches/etc. to take into consideration. Other states may have additional stricter requirements, but CA does for sure and they are much more strict and extensive.

Comment: A walk-in closet is a room.

Answer (score 3):

Code doesn’t specify a location for the light switch it can be inside or outside so a code reference is not available.

The only limit is the height at 6’7”

NEC 410 can get you started for luminaries and closets 410.16 in the closet then 410.48 general wiring but no requirement for the location.
More on switches in article 404 And again the height max is the only limit.